# Applescript Get value of property by string name of property

Tags: properties, applescript

In AppleScript. Let's say I have a record with a property called Title.

Let's say I set a variable to the text "Title"; can I use that variable to get the value of the property Title?  Basically, is there any way to do something like this:

```
set result to property named "Title" of myRecord
```

Instead of:

```
set result to Title of myRecord
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the task you're working on? A record is a set of properties (aka 'struct'), not an arbitrary key-value collection (aka dictionary/hash/map). There are ways to muck about with a record's innards but they're all evil hacks with all sorts of nasty gotchas. Far better to use the right data structure for the job.

Comment: @CraigSmith - Yes, of course I tried it.

Comment: @foo - I didn't know enough when I posted the question to use the correct terminology. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I also realize I didn't ask the correct question. The value I'm trying to obtain is from a property list item.

Here's what I learned, and how to accomplish this:

```
use framework "Foundation"

set _plist to ...

set _objcPlist to GetAppleScriptObjectAsObjcObject(_plist)

set _value to GetObjcPropertyValueByName("MyProperty", item 1 of _objcPlist)

on GetAppleScriptObjectAsObjcObject(asObject)
    set a to current application
    set cClass to class of asObject

    if (cClass is record) then
        return a's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithDictionary:asObject
    else if (cClass is list) then
        return a's NSArray's arrayWithArray:asObject
    else
        error "Unexpected Class Type"
    end if
end GetAppleScriptObjectAsObjcObject

on GetObjcPropertyValueByName(propertyName, objcItem)
    return (objcItem's valueForKey:propertyName) as text
end GetObjcPropertyValueByName
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try the try ... on error approach:

```
set aRecord to {title:"hello world", author:"who's who"}

try
    aRecord as Unicode text
on error error_message
    set err to error_message
end try
err

-- "Can’t make {title:\"hello world\", author:\"who's who\"} into type Unicode text."
```

then parse err (it's text now). it depends on the complexity of aRecord, if it's a record of nested lists, or records; the parsing would be very complicated. have fun :)